# Realm executeTransactionAsync for write

Tags: android, android-asynctask, realm

Hello I am trying to write data to two tables based on switch case inside executeTransactionAsync. I am getting error as

```
05-31 14:37:29.811 22582-22582/com.app.attendancesystem W/System.err: java.lang.ClassCastException: io.realm.EmployeeRealmProxy cannot be cast to model.EmpTimeLog
05-31 14:37:29.811 22582-22582/com.app.attendancesystem W/System.err:     at util.DatabaseOperation$9.execute(DatabaseOperation.java:269)
05-31 14:37:29.811 22582-22582/com.app.attendancesystem W/System.err:     at io.realm.Realm$2.run(Realm.java:1295)
05-31 14:37:29.811 22582-22582/com.app.attendancesystem W/System.err:     at io.realm.internal.async.BgPriorityRunnable.run(BgPriorityRunnable.java:34)
05-31 14:37:29.811 22582-22582/com.app.attendancesystem W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
05-31 14:37:29.811 22582-22582/com.app.attendancesystem W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
05-31 14:37:29.811 22582-22582/com.app.attendancesystem W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
05-31 14:37:29.811 22582-22582/com.app.attendancesystem W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
05-31 14:37:29.811 22582-22582/com.app.attendancesystem W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Here is my code for executeTransactionAsync

```
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        try {
            cancelAsync();

            asyncTransaction = realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
                @Override
                public void execute(Realm bgRealm) {
                    switch (tag) {
                        case Config.TAG_EMP: {
                            ArrayList<Employee> mArrEmp = (ArrayList<Employee>) mArrObj;
                            Config.debug("Arr size inside " + mArrEmp.size());
                            for (int i = 0; i < mArrEmp.size(); i++) {
                                int id;
                                if (bgRealm.where(Employee.class).max("id") == null) {
                                    id = 1;
                                } else {
                                    id = bgRealm.where(Employee.class).max("id").intValue() + 1;
                                }
                                Config.error("Id val " + id);
                                mArrEmp.get(i).setId(id);
                                bgRealm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(mArrEmp.get(i));
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                        case Config.TAG_LOG:{
                            ArrayList<EmpTimeLog> mArrEmpTimeLog = (ArrayList<EmpTimeLog>) mArrObj;
                            Config.debug("Arr size inside " + mArrEmpTimeLog.size());
                            for (int i = 0; i < mArrEmpTimeLog.size(); i++) {
                                int id;
                                if (bgRealm.where(EmpTimeLog.class).max("logId") == null) {
                                    id = 1;
                                } else {
                                    id = bgRealm.where(EmpTimeLog.class).max("logId").intValue() + 1;
                                }
                                Config.error("Id val " + id);
                                mArrEmpTimeLog.get(i).setLogId(id);
                                bgRealm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(mArrEmpTimeLog.get(i));

                            }
                                break;
                        }
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }, new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    mReceiver.onCompleteInsertion(tag, msg);
                }
            }, new Realm.Transaction.OnError() {
                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable error) {
                    error.printStackTrace();
                    mReceiver.onDatabaseError(Config.DATABASE_INSERT_ERROR, "Error while inserting " + error.getMessage());
                }
            });


        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            mErrorOccured = true;
            Config.error("Error occurred " + ex.getMessage());
        }
```

And model files :

```
public class Employee extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    private int id=1;
    private String empName="";

    public String getEmpName() {
        return empName;
    }

    public void setEmpName(String empName) {
        this.empName = empName;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
public class EmpTimeLog extends RealmObject{

    @PrimaryKey
    private int logId=1;
    private Date signInTime;
    private Date signOutTime;

    private int empId;

    public int getEmpId() {
        return empId;
    }

    public void setEmpId(int empId) {
        this.empId = empId;
    }

    public int getLogId() {
        return logId;
    }

    public void setLogId(int logId) {
        this.logId = logId;
    }

    public Date getSignInTime() {
        return signInTime;
    }

    public void setSignInTime(Date signInTime) {
        this.signInTime = signInTime;
    }

    public Date getSignOutTime() {
        return signOutTime;
    }

    public void setSignOutTime(Date signOutTime) {
        this.signOutTime = signOutTime;
    }


}
```

My doubt is : Do I need to write separate async transaction for every write?

Comment: No you don't. What is the line the error is thrown?

Comment: where does `tag` come from?

Comment: @TimCastelijns  mArrEmpTimeLog.get(i).setLogId(id); this is the line

Comment: @Emanuelez thats my logic of notifying fragment/activity about task done

Comment: Are you sure it's not here? `ArrayList<EmpTimeLog> mArrEmpTimeLog = (ArrayList<EmpTimeLog>) mArrObj;`

Comment: @TimCastelijns Silly Mistake. thanks :-) getting this error now . W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'value' belongs to a different Realm. @                                 bgRealm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(mArrEmpTimeLog.get(i));
 this line

Comment: @TimCastelijns I am total new to this realm thing :-)

Comment: @Manoj update your question please since you have a different problemnow